# 'int' object error when looking' for text after strong tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Trying to get the text after a strong tag - here it would be 2.13.4 
Html im trying to get =

`/strong Gross Time:/strong 2.13.4`

The error I'm getting is:

**`int` object has no attribute `next_sibling`**

Please help with my code!

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    webpage_response = s.get('http://www.harness.org.au/racing/fields/race-fields/?mc=SW010420')
    soup = bs(webpage_response.content, "html.parser")
    #soup1 = soup.select('.content')
    results = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'forPrint'})
    for race in results:
        tableoftimes = race.find('table', class_='raceTimes').get_text()
        grosstime = str(tableoftimes).find('.Gross Time:').next_sibling.string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grosstime = str(tableoftimes).find('.Gross Time:').next_sibling.string
```

First you're converting `tableoftimes` to a `str`, which is not necessary because `get_text()` is guaranteed to return a string.

Then you are looking for the position of the substring `'.Gross Time:'` in `tableoftimes` string, which returns an `int`.

Finally you are calling `next_sibling` on an integer, hence the error.

Comment: this worked 
```
         trackrating = tableoftimes.find(text="Track Rating:").findPrevious('td').contents[1]
         grosstime = tableoftimes.find(text="Track Rating:").findNext('td').contents[1]
```